# Cakephp 3: Hydrating nested entities in query results

Tags: cakephp-3.0

**Just to level-set:**
CakePHP 3 introduces Entity objects which can represent an ORM (database) record as an object rather than an array. Creating the object from the raw data is called "hydration". This has pros and cons, depending on what you're trying to achieve, so CakePHP gives you the option to control hydration through the hydrate() function which can be chained in the query.

What I've observed is only the top level results are hydrated; nested results are not. So if my query is something like:

```
$authors=$this->Authors->find("all")->contain("Books");
$this->set("authors",$authors);
```

will return something along the lines of

```
authors (array)  << This is an array since we can have multiple records
  0  (object)   <<< This is the Entity object representing the first Author 
    id 1
    name "Roger Kaplan"
    [other author fields]
    books (array) <<< This is an array because there are multiple books
      0 (array)  <<< I expect this to be an entity object!!
         id 100
         title "CakePHP Made Easy"
         [other book fields]
      1 (array) <<< I want this to be an entity too
         id 101
         title "Solving Java-induced Neuroses"
         [other book fields]
```

Is it possible to have the nested entities hydrated as well?

The reason I'm asking is that I'm building helpers which expect an entity object to be passed, and uses the metadata on the entity object to do interesting things. I want to be able to pass nested records as well as top-level ones.

EDIT:
Something I just noticed is that belongsTo associations, which will only contain  one record, will be inserted as an array of values (ie not an entity) while hasMany associations will return an array of entities. Here is the dump from my actual project; I've attempted to edit it down for clarity:

```
$message = $this->Messages->find("all")->where(["Messages.id" => $message_id])->contain(["MessageBodies","JobOrders","Candidates"])->first();
```

Messages **belongsTo** Candidates and JobOrders, and **hasMany** MessageBodies.

Here is a rendering of the result:

```
message(array)
    id 1
    job_order_id 2
    candidate_id 1
    candidate(array)
        id 1
        first_name Roger
        last_name Kaplan
    job_order(array)
        id 2
        name Chief Cook and Bottle Washer
    message_bodies(array)
        0(object)
        1(object)
        2(object)
```

So if my assumption is correct, that only hasMany associations are returned as an array of entities, the question is, how can I get belongsTo (and possibly hasOne, which I tend not to use) contained data to show up as Entity's?

Comment: It's strange because usually nested entities are hydrated too.

Comment: is that your actual code or is just an example?

Comment: Just an example. I didn't want to post my "real" code since it would require background on my schema and db info, so I used the schema from the tutorials. But I think I just noticed something which I'll add to the question.. hasMany relationships seem to return an array of entities while belongsTo returns a single record in an array.

Comment: You're assumption is incorrect. By default, all associations are being hydrated. So either you are experiencing a bug, or there's something in your application that prevents hydration, or dehydrates these specific associations afterwards. However, without seeing all relevant code, all people can do is shooting in the dark.

Comment: OK I think I see the source of my confusion. The data passed into the view does indeed contain nested entities, as verified by the debugger. I was using the variable viewer in the Cake toolbar to look into the structure, and that view was reporting the embedded entities as arrays. Based on that data, I was reaching into the structure with ["array syntax"] but the Cake entity is smart enough to intercept that and convert to get() calls.

Answer (score 0):

The data passed into the view does indeed contain nested entities, as verified by the debugger. I was using the variable viewer in the Cake toolbar to look into the structure, and that view was reporting the embedded entities as arrays. Based on that data, I was reaching into the structure with ["array syntax"] but the Cake entity is smart enough to intercept that and convert to get() calls.